# How to transfer a file from a remote linux machine using SCP with Mingw on Windows7

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, scp, mingw

If I am logged into a linux machine via SSH in a mingw window in windows 7;

How do I transfer a file to my local machine?

I am imagining something like:

```
scp <filename> address_of_local_machine/mydirectory
```

However I don't know how to get the `address_of_local_machine`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two solutions to this:

1. Get the address of your local machine. If It is part of the normal Internet (e.g. no weird things like NAT) then a simple [start], [run], `cmd`, `ipconfig` will show you your local IP. From the shell on the linux box type `scp <filename> address_of_local_machine:/mydirectory`
2. Do it the other way around. On your windows box use [start], [run], `cmd`, `scp my_directory/filename name_of_linux_box:`

The last requires you to have a scp program on windows. PuTTY is the most used program for that.  (Example `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe d:\myfile linuxbox:`)

[MingGW](http://www.mingw.org/) also comes with a scp client, but I do not know the default path for that. Hence the putty example.